Use Control plane API to Create Share at Azure File with share key
I used the control plane API to create a share at Azure File.
API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/file-shares/create?view=rest-storagerp-2023-01-01&tabs=HTTP
The HTTP request:
PUT /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/fileServices/default/shares/sharename?api-version=2023-01-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: management.azure.com
Authorization: SharedKey ***:***
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Content-Length: 17
x-ms-date: Thu, 18 Apr 2024 09:26:55 GMT
x-ms-version: 2023-01-01

I got an error :
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/***", error="invalid_token", error_description="The authentication scheme of SharedKey is not supported."
Does the control API only support OAuth authentication?

Is the solutiom worked for you?


Does the Control API only support OAuth authentication?

According to this MS-Document:
Yes, the Control API supports only OAuth2 authentication (Bearer token).

API to Create Share at Azure File with share key

You can use the below request to create a file share with a shared key.
Request:
PUT https://venkat123.file.core.windows.net/myshare?restype=share 
Request Headers:
x-ms-version: 2023-11-03 
x-ms-date: Thu, 18 Apr 2024 10:24:55 GMT 
Authorization: SharedKey <Your storage account name>:xxxxxMesKNh0xxxxJdjidOQ=

Output:

Portal:

Reference:
Create Share (FileREST API) - Azure Files | Microsoft Learn
